Extension for Representing the code graphically in VS code
enter image description here
Hi, Is there any extension available to visualize the code as above the image in Vs code.
This visualize code will help us understand the code and debug as soon as possible. Is there any extension available please let me know.
Is it possible to do integrate with any IDE (Vs-code ,Embedded ide like (Atmel ide,S32-Design tool)) etc..
It will help us to understand the code and debug, As I am embedded software engineer, Debugging the code is very difficult and to understand the code.
This visualize code could help us understand in better way and we can avoid bug while testing in real world.
